ADF pagination with offset
I have an activity copy in azure data factory to get data from a REST API, so the response content has an offset that I have to get to extract the seconde page and so on until the end
This an example of my first get

`{
    "records": [
        {
            "id": "rechBUmxzSWr3WnCy",
            "createdTime": "2024-10-23T08:45:24Z",
            "fields": {
                "public_url": "https://video.xxxxx.xx/details/des-le-23-fevrier",
                "Date de création": "2024-10-23T08:45:24Z",
                "Republier?": {
                    "label": "Republier",
                    "url": "https://xxxxx.xx"
                },
                "Créé par": {
                    "id": "usrFXl0L9XONgHBkn",
                    "email": "jptittley@xxxxx.xx",
                    "name": "J. ttley"
                },
                "rec_ID": {
                    "label": "Forcer maintenant",
                    "url": "https://make.com/Wr3WnCy"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "rec7uO2QuI0X787kn",
            "createdTime": "2024-11-02T08:45:19Z",
            "fields": {
                "public_url": "https://video.xxxxx.xx/details/bande-annonce",
                "Date de création": "2024-11-02T08:45:19Z",
                "Republier?": {
                    "label": "Republier",
                    "url": "https://xxxxx.xx"
                },
                "Créé par": {
                    "id": "usrFXl0L9XONgHBkn",
                    "email": "jptittley@xxxxx.xx",
                    "name": "J. ttley"
                },
                "rec_ID": {
                    "label": "Forcer maintenant",
                    "url": "https://.make.com/0X787kn"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "offset": "itrpkeGlLhcNWsdcB/recqEeeUJ0Ab8JFFb",
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (Canada Central)",
    "executionDuration": 6,
    "durationInQueue": {
        "integrationRuntimeQueue": 0
    },
    "billingReference": {
        "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
        "billableDuration": [
            {
                "meterType": "AzureIR",
                "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                "unit": "Hours"
            }
        ]
    }
}`

I tried many combined pagination rule but no one worked, any help will be appreciated.
Thanks
I'm trying to get data from a REST API to Azure SQL Database]

canyou add your sample URL example
